# Xcode crashes when exporting project for localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, crash

I am facing a problem here. When I want to export my project for localization, the xcode crashes with this eror:

[image]

I have tried several approaches including looking at "substringWithRange" properties inside my code but no such property is used inside my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and I found the solution to myself, just for reference to others if anyone encounters this problem.

Delete all your localizable.Strings and info.plist strings, delete your languages and start all over again, not too sure where the problem was but restarting the translation procedure solved the problem.